# Modify rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe as shown below :

```
items_0_trialAreas_0_id   items_0_trialAreas_0_name    items_1_trialAreas_0_id     items_1_trialAreas_0_name    items_2_trialAreas_0_id     items_2_trialAreas_0_name .....
    1                              it1                           2                             it2                       3                             it3
```

I want to modify my dataframe such that , all item_id's are under one column and all item_name's are under one column.

Like this :

```
item_trialAreas_ids      item_trialAreas_names
    1                           it1
    2                           it2
    3                           it3
   ...                          ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
new_df =(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),['item_id','item_name'],
                         j='n',i='index',sep = '_')
           .reset_index(drop=True)
           .rename(columns = {'item_id':'items_id','item_name':'item_names'}) )

print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  items_ids item_names
0       1.0        it1
1       2.0        it2
2       3.0        NaN
3       NaN        it3
```

---

**Initial df:**

```
print(df)
   item_id_1 item_name_1  item_id_2 item_name_2  item_id_3 item_name_4
0          1         it1          2         it2          3         it3
```

Comment: But what if the Initial DF column names are like this : ```items_0_Areas_0_id | items_0_Areas_0_name | items_0_Areas_1_id | items_0_Areas_1_name ```

Comment: then you need change the name of columns previously

Comment: could you update your question with the real names of your columns?

Comment: Updated my question with real names of columns. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

First to create your sample Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

rows = [1, 'it1', 2, 'it2', 3, 'it3']
cols = ['items_0_trialAreas_0_id', 'items_0_trialAreas_0_name', 'items_1_trialAreas_0_id', 'items_1_trialAreas_0_name', 'items_2_trialAreas_0_id', 'items_2_trialAreas_0_name']

df = pd.DataFrame(rows).T
df.columns = cols
```

Then add:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,::2].T.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)
df2 = df.iloc[:,1::2].T.reset_index().drop('index', axis=1)

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df_final.columns = ['item_trialAreas_ids', 'item_trialAreas_names']
```

Output:

```
  item_trialAreas_ids item_trialAreas_names
0                   1                   it1
1                   2                   it2
2                   3                   it3
```